# How to open a web page itno another site without iframe?

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, window

I have a web page that I want to open in other sites, but I don't want that my web page will not be opened in an iframe, because once the iframe is opened, I can not resize it from the page in the iframe neither resize it.
How can I do this? It's this possible?

Could someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: yes, just gather the page with a plain ajax request (for example) and then insert DOM into your page (jQuery will take care of many details if you can use it).

Comment: did you try something already ? You could use AJAX if the other page is on the same domain as the caller, or server-side code (possibly coupled to ajax), but I don't see any more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can load html from a remote location & set it as the content of an element in the page. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details on how it works.